# PS3 1080p Image Quality Issue on Samsung LED

Tags: ps3

I just purchased a new Samsung UN55ES7003 to replace an older 46" model (LN46A650). Images originating from my DirecTV DVR (1080i and lower) seem to be fine, but something's happening between the PS3 (at 1080p) and the new TV. Basically what I'm noticing is:

- There is a vertical jitter - the image appears to slightly move up and then back to normal.
- There are horizontal, white lines in the bottom right corner of the screen.

This happens in any PS3 content: menu, in game, and in movie.

What I've tried:

- Switching HDMI cables (doesn't fix)
- A different HDMI port on the TV (doesn't fix)
- Try a different AV receiver (doesn't fix)
- Connected the PS3 back to the old set (issue goes away...as expected)

Thus, I feel I've sufficiently ruled out all possible hardware issues with the exception of the new TV. Why I'm convinced it's only 1080p: I re-connected the PS3 back to the NEW TV, and went into PS3 Video Setup and cycled through all of the supported resolutions. NONE of the resolutions exhibited the image jitter/interference issue EXCEPT 1080p.

I happen to have a standalone BD player and plan tomorrow to connect it to the new TV and see if the 1080p image from it also has the same problem. At that point, I will be convinced that it's an issue with the new TV handling 1080p content (which would be shocking; I've never had a problem with a Samsung TV).

All of this said, if I find that the BD player also has this problem at 1080p, and it appears to be the TV, I guess I'll contact Samsung and/or the seller to start the RMA process, unless someone here can propose a setting change or firmware update that might fix this?

Comment: I had a similar issues with my PS3 a few years ago, and they originated from interfaces from my cable box. You say you have a DVR connected to your setup, could you disconnect your antenna cable from your DVR and see if the issue persists? Also, try connecting your PS3 directly to your TV and not through a receiver and see if this still happens

Comment: the quality of TVs you buy on black friday are not the best. regardless of brand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the Samsung SyncPlus service causing signal interference.  By disabling SyncPlus in the Smart Hub interface, the issue went away.

Answer (score -2):

its samsung issue.
you need to uncheck 1080p mode in ps3 screen settings.
there should be 3 modes: 576p, 720p and 1080i.
so in 1080i mode will work without any issue.